# UCanAccess: No suitable driver found

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc, ucanaccess

I keep getting the 'No suitable driver found' in my database and I can't pin down what's wrong with my connect class? Any help? I've got all 5 jars in. I want to connect to a Microsoft Access Database.

```
import java.sql.*;

public class Connect
{
public Connection con;
Statement st;
public Connect()
{
    try  {
        Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess:E://EclipsePortable//Data//workspace//ThisWillWork//res//Railway.accdb");
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
     }
     catch(Exception err) {
       System.out.println(err);
     }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your jdbc url is wrong,  you lost a //, see other examples

Comment: Specifically `jdbc:ucanaccess://E:/EclipsePortable/Data/workspace/ThisWillWork/res/Railway.accdb`